# Пропуск инструкции

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование, mysqli

Всем привет,не могу разобраться второй день с данной проблемой,ушёл в `mysqli`.
Проблема пропуска второй инструкции осталась. При нарочном допущении ошибки в `mysqli_connect` ошибку выбивает на ура. При нарочном допущении ошибки в выборе БД,нечего не происходит. Хоть я пишу `id2134350_greendale`, хоть оставлю пустым местом,всёравно проходит true.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id2134350_egor", "26718323aA");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

    echo " fuck off";

    exit();

}

$selecting = mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"id2134350_greendale");

if (!$selecting) 
{

    echo "suck";

}
```

Comment: Всё отлично,только не работает.

Comment: Вы лучше через `var_dump(mysqli_select_db($mysqli,"id2134350_greendale"));` выведите информацию и покажите, что на экране при выборе существующей и не существующей бд выводится!? А так же что написано в логе ошибок на сервере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае код работает верно, если не указывать к какой базе подключиться, то просто будет подключение к базе по умолчанию.

Выполните вот такой код и увидите что в первом случае тоже идет подключение, и увидите к какой именно базе, во втором уже увидите что подключение идет уже именно к той базе которую вы запросили.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id2134350_egor", "26718323aA");

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "id2134350_greendale");

if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Если хотите чтобы была ошибка при подключении не к вашей базе `id2134350_greendale` а другой, тогда проверяйте к какой базе сейчас подключение и выдавайте ошибку если это не `id2134350_greendale`

Comment: Спасибо большое что объяснили. Теперь понятно почему нет ошибки.